# Right Single Quotation Mark (U+2018) being replaced by Apostrophe (U+0027) in iTerm2

Tags: iterm, copy-paste

I use iTerm2 (version 3.50beta10) on my Mac (macOS 13.2.1). Whenever I paste a **right single quotation mark** (U+2018) aka (’) into a terminal window, it is replaced by an  apostrophe (‘) (U+0027).

**Can I disable that somehow?**

I am pasting using  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>.

(I am aware I could use <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>  for "Advanced Paste" to open a dialog and then <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>  <kbd>⏎ Return</kbd> to paste my test, but I don't want more keys and more steps. I want it to paste what I copied.)

Comment: Is this happening in Terminal as well?  What about other Apps like TextEdit?

Comment: Not in Terminal. Not in other apps.

Comment: So, we’ve narrowed it down to iTerm.  Look in iTerm Preferences in the keyboard tab and see if you have any replacements, shortcuts, etc.  Side question… why are you running a beta of iTerm rather than a stable release?

Comment: Sadly, I can't find anything in the preferences. It's a long-standing annoyance, so I don't think it's related to this beta. If it's there (and there are approx 1M options) it's not named or placed obviously.

Comment: When you open a new window, are you using the default shell or do you have a custom command?  It might also be helpful to query the folks at iTerm - let them know it’s only happening in their app.  One more Q….are you using OMZ by any chance?

Comment: I would expect this to be intended _helpful_ by iTerm when pasting in mangled code from web sites (where the opposite process happened in order to be more readable).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an app called [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/).

This can allow you to set macros that can do what you're wanting.

E.g. - you could set up a macro like (only in application iTerm2) when I paste " RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2018) aka ’ ", backspace one character and type "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2018) aka ’".

Not the perfect solution but an easy workaround.